# Getting number of command line arguments, NASM

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

As far as I know, at the beginning of execution `[esp]` contains the number of command line arguments. So I'm doing this:

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
format  db  "%d", 0

section .text
main:
    push format
    call printf
    add esp, 4

    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

However, it prints garbage like -145184962. This code gives the same result:

```
push dword [esp]
push format
call printf
add esp, 8
```

Code is builded with `nasm -f elf32 a.asm` and `gcc -m32 a.o`.

Comment: You pushed the format but you didn't push the value you want to print in the first code snippet, so it printed garbage(actually it would have been the previous value pushed on stack which was the return address pushed by the function call to `main`). The second scenario you are also printing the return address at the top of the stack which sits as [ESP]. [ESP+4] would be number of arguments. [ESP+8] would be the pointer to the array of `char *` pointers that represent each string parameter passed on the command line. Number of arguments will be at least 1 since first argument is program name.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you a lot. I really forgot about the return address in stack.